# inserting data in td of large table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a HTML table that looks somewhat like this

```
<tr rel="price">
    <th>Price</th>
    <td class="">-</td>
    <td class="">-</td>
    <td class="">-</td>
    <td class="">-</td>
</tr>
```

how would i insert data the the 4th td? I could give the 4th td an ID and insert like this

```
$('#id').html('bla bla');
```

but my table has 60 rows and 4 columns. Personally think it would be abit messy if i was going to add ID's to all td's. Any suggestions? Obviously something that works fast on a big table would be ideal. Thanks

Comment: try nth selector `$('table tbody tr td:nth(3)').html();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("tr[rel=price] td:nth-child(3)").html('bla bla');
```

3 is because counting starts at 0, so that is the 4th element.

Answer (score 5):

Try using [:nth](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) selector

```
$('table tbody tr td:nth(3)').html();
```

or

```
$('table tbody tr td:nth-child(3)').html();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr rel="price" id="tr1">
    <th>Price</th>
    <td class="">-</td>
    <td class="">-</td>
    <td class="">-</td>
    <td class="">-</td>
</tr>

$('table tbody #tr1').closest("td").eq(3).html('bla bla');
```